# MySQl MariaDB group timestamp by points

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb, unix-timestamp

**I have the following:**

- data points collected per day with associated `date` - unix timestamp.

**I am trying to achieve the following:**

- **Filter data points per day.** i.e suppose I have 4 data points per day, I am trying to reduce it to `n` data points per day using `GROUP BY`.

**I am using the following query:**

```
    SELECT *,FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)/((1440/n)*60))    
    AS timekey 
    FROM  `tbl`
    where date < 'date'  
    GROUP BY timekey)m
    UNION
    (SELECT * ,0 As timekey FROM  `tbl` 
    where date > 'date'  );
```

This according to me should generate timekey for the data points for any row with date < given_date_in_query.

`n` determines the number of points to be grouped by.

Then the `GROUP BY` should ultimately reduce the number of data points with respect to `n`.

> The above query works for a table with more than `20000 rows`.
>
> for `n=2` the datapoints before the specified `date` are reduced to 2 points(to 2 rows from 4).

**Here is the create script:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_a` (
  `id` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
   ---
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   ---
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `phase_id_2` (`phase_id`,`date`),
   KEY `id` (`id`,`pid`),
   KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The query works perfectly for the above table.

However when I try the same query with another db with comparatively less rows it does not work as expected.

It reduces only the date specified in the query and the rest remain untouched.

> .i.e only the row corresponding to the given_date in the query is
>   reduced by the query and the rest of the rows remain untouched.

**Test table create script:**

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Could this be an index error or a database engine exception?

**Steps to recreate the problem:**
  **Create test tbl :**

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Insert data:**

```
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2015-11-01 00:00:00');  
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2015-11-01 06:00:00');  
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2015-11-01 12:00:00');   
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2015-11-01 18:00:00');   
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2016-11-01 00:00:00');  
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2016-11-01 06:00:00');  
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2016-11-01 12:00:00');  
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2016-11-01 18:00:00');   
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2016-11-02 00:00:00');  
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2016-11-02 06:00:00');  
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2016-11-02 12:00:00');   
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2016-11-02 18:00:00');  
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2017-11-02 00:00:00');  
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2017-11-02 06:00:00');  
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2017-11-02 12:00:00');    
INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES ('2017-11-02 18:00:00');
```

**Run Query:**

```
 SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *,FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)/((1440/2)*60))    
    AS timekey 
    FROM  `test`
    where date < '2017-11-02'  
    GROUP BY timekey) m
    UNION
    (SELECT * ,0 As timekey FROM  `test` 
    where date > '2017-11-02');
```

The above should:

- reduce all data points prior to `2017-11-02` which should give a result of 10.

Comment: Your code seems to do what you intend:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=687faeb2962703cc812ab8e43c3b0563.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for the fiddle, i had no clue about it.

The query works on mariadb versions, however when i run it with mysql, the query fails.

I get the following error:  

`Functional dependency is not available when the mode ONLY FULL GROUP BY is active`

I got it working by changing the `SQL_MODE` property in .ini.

Now the query works for large sets of rows but fails when the number of rows is less.

Is there a work around for this?

I need the query to work across with different databases and versions.

I am at my wits end :p !!

Comment: @GordonLinoff The main issue is, the query is working on tables with large number of rows.
I am wondering how the working is dependent on the number of rows!!